# Difference in paths for the base tag?

Tags: html, radix

I'm using the base tag

```
<base href="http://my_domain.com/web/source/" target="_blank">
```

but the domain will vary so I want to use

```
<base href="/web/source/" target="_blank">
```

or

```
<base href="web/source/" target="_blank">
```

Which one should I use.  Obviously I could just try both, but I want to understand why I should use the appropriate one.

Per, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base), both absolute and relative paths are allowed.  The docs say `see note selection below` but I see no note section.

Comment: Both of them should work alright, there's no one _correct_ way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the preceding slash (/) will always ensure that the browser goes back to the root of the domain.

Leaving out the preceding slash could potentially send your users to /web/source/web/source/page.ext.